# Moodle: The frontpage is empty.

Tags: moodle

I'm trying to display a courses block in the frontpage for my students but it's empty.

[Here is a screenshot of my frontpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/143UB.png)

This student is enrolled in a course and I've already checked the permissions for the block and Students and Teachers are supposed to be able to see it but still nothing happens.

Is there anyway of achieving this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the block code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Admin, go to menu Site Administration/Front Page/Front Page Settings and in Frontpage section select de option "List of courses".

[image]